# API access authentication/application key (django/nginx/gunicorn)

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a web app created in django, running in gunicorn app server behind nginx webserver/reverse-proxy. I need to have external application to access some processed data (csv/json), for which I need some sort of authentication. The basic django auth/login is not optimal as a simple script needs to pull the data with a simple request, no cookies etc (not created by me).

For now, I have

1. set up the service being available with https/tls only
2. created an IP-filter in django to reduce the "attack surface" with:

`request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']`

and using nginx to forward the ip with:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Next I was thinking to include and application key (hash of a pw or something) which needs to be included in the request, and is checked against db for a list of valid keys.

Is this a suitable api authentication or is there something else which can be used/recomennded? some sort of application key framework?

Answer (score 1):

There are many authentication methods beside of session/cookie based ones. For your case I will suggest simple token authentication. Just save same token in your django app and external app and on each request from external app to django, send additional header:

```
Authentication: Token YOUR_TOKEN_KEY
```

Now all you need to do in django is to fetch that token and check if it matches one saved locally.

If you want more auth options for API, check [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

Comment: Sounds exactly what I was looking for, going to try this. Thanks!